# Connecting a Java desktop app to Firebase-analytics

Tags: firebase, desktop-application, firebase-analytics, google-bigquery

I have three types of clients that work with my server at the moment: Android, Web (Angular) and а Desktop-application written in Java. There is a need to send events to Firebase-analytics from each client. I am clear on how to send events from Android and the Web - this is described in the documentation. But i can't find the way to send events from desktop-app. So, i have several questions:

1. Is this option possible?
2. Maybe the answer, is to send events to BigQuery? So, what is the difference between sending events to Firebase-analytics and BigQuery (via the REST API or using client libraries) associated with Firebase-analytics?

Answer (score 1):

1. There are only client libraries for web and mobile apps.  Desktop apps are not supported.
2. You could certainly have your desktop app send data to BigQuery, in order to augment existing data from Firebase that you export to it.  If you do this, you will have to create your own queries to analyze the data - the Firebase console will not be able to see the data you put there directly.

Comment: So, i would not be able to use all features of firebase-analytics, such as AdMob or Google Ads?

Comment: I don't think those products have desktop app support either.

Comment: thank you, i will try to find solution executing JS-code in java application

Comment: @A.Kashnikov, have you managed to find to find a solution for this?